# Reference file from different directory inside block jade

Tags: pug

I am trying to pull in an element from a different folder into a jade block.

```
extends ../generic-app-elements/_appLayout
block titlebar
    ../generic-app-elements/titlebar
```

`extends` works fine, as it can handle the `../`, however the browser throws `is not a valid class name` errors on the `../` inside the `block`. How can I get jade to treat this like any other block code?

Answer (score 0):

Use include

```
extends ../generic-app-elements/_appLayout
block titlebar
    include '../generic-app-elements/titlebar'
```